# value cannot be passed into another public static method (java)

Tags: java, static

This is my DAO. It consists of `public static method for presentationBean`, `public static method for lecturerBean` and lastly, `public static PresentationBean addavailable2(PresentationBean ADbean)` to access the database.

```
public class AddAvailableDAO2 {

        static Connection currentCon = null;
        static ResultSet rs = null;


        public static PresentationBean getPresentation(String id) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
        {
            currentCon = JavaConnectionDB.getConnection() ;
            PreparedStatement ps = currentCon.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM presentation WHERE presentationid = ?") ;
            ps.setString(1, id) ;
            PresentationBean pb = new PresentationBean() ;
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery() ;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                pb.setPresentationID(rs.getString(1)) ;
                pb.setPresentationDay(rs.getString(2)) ;
                pb.setPresentationStart(rs.getDate(3)) ;
                pb.setPresentationEnd(rs.getDate(4)) ;
            }

            return pb ;
        }
        public static LecturerBean getLecturer(String lectID) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
        {
            currentCon = JavaConnectionDB.getConnection() ;
            PreparedStatement ps1 = currentCon.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM lecturer WHERE lecturerid = ?") ;
            ps1.setString(1, lectID) ;
            LecturerBean lb = new LecturerBean() ;
            ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery() ;
            while(rs1.next())
            {
                lb.setLecturerID(rs1.getString(1)) ;

            }

            return lb ;
        }
        public static PresentationBean addavailable2(PresentationBean ADbean) {

            System.out.println("JIJIJI");

            AvailabilityBean available = new AvailabilityBean();

            String availableID = ADbean.getPresentationID();
            String availableDay = ADbean.getPresentationDay();
            String availID = available.getAvailableID();

            LecturerBean lb = new LecturerBean();
            String lecturerID = lb.getLecturerID();

        try{  

                currentCon = JavaConnectionDB.getConnection();


                  SimpleDateFormat date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
                  Date availStart = ADbean.getPresentationStart();
                  Date availEnd = ADbean.getPresentationEnd();

                  String avs = date1.format(availStart);
                  String ave = date1.format(availEnd);

                  String start = "02-05-2016 " + avs.substring(11);
                  String end = "02-05-2016 " + ave.substring(11);



                  Date StartTime = date1.parse(start);
                  Date EndTime = date1.parse(end);

                  java.util.Date availableStart = new java.util.Date();
                  java.sql.Date avStart = new java.sql.Date(StartTime.getTime());
                  java.util.Date availableEnd = new java.util.Date();
                  java.sql.Date avEnd = new java.sql.Date(EndTime.getTime());

                PreparedStatement ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("Insert into free (freeID,lecturerID,availableID) select free_seq.nextval,?,availableID from availability where availableday=? AND availableStart=?");

                ps.setString(1,lecturerID);  //PASS THE VALUE TO HERE
                ps.setString(2,availableDay);
                ps.setDate(3, avStart);


                ps.executeUpdate();  


             }

        catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("add availability failed 2: An Exception has occurred! " + e);
          e.printStackTrace() ;

                System.out.println("Your availability Day is " + availableDay);



        }  

    return ADbean;
    }
```

My problem is, I can't pass the value of lecturerID from `public static method for lecturerBean` to `public static PresentationBean addavailable2(PresentationBean ADbean)` because `lecturerID` does not exist in `PresentationBean`. I am aware of that.

So how can i pass the `lecturerID` from `public static method for lecturerBean` to `public static PresentationBean addavailable2(PresentationBean ADbean)`. I tried to declare new `LecturerBean` in `public static PresentationBean addavailable2(PresentationBean ADbean)`but I am still getting null value.

Comment: No need to state the whole method header. Method names are fine.

Comment: Declare it as a class variable

Comment: It looks like `addavailable2` needs a lecturer ID, and you're not giving it one.  So the obvious solution is to give it one, by adding another parameter to the method.

Comment: You may want to change the signature of addavailable2(PresentationBean adBean, LectureBean lectureBean), this will allow you to pass lecture info from the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass both adBean and lecturerBean to method addavaialable2 i.e.

```
public static PresentationBean addavailable2(final PresentationBean adBean, final LectureBean lecturerBean) {

        AvailabilityBean available = new AvailabilityBean();

        String availableID = adBean.getPresentationID();
        String availableDay = adBean.getPresentationDay();
        String lecturerID = lecturerBean.getLecturerID();
        String availID = available.getAvailableID();
        .......
```

In your caller unlike before you will need to perform the following

```
//Get input presentation bean, using your desired id
PresentationBean presentationBean = AddAvailableDAO2.getPresentation("123");
//Get input lecturer bean, using your desired id
LecturerBean lecturerBean = AddAvailableDAO2.getLecturer("456");
//Add availability
AddAvailableDAO2.addavailable2(presentationBean, lecturerBean);
...
```

I think you get the idea here. PresentationBean and LecturerBean represent two different entities/objects and therefore if you want to associate a lecturer to a presentation you need access to both entities. Hope that makes sense.